Textual non-uniformity of the Ten Commandments
The first apparent impression of reading the Ten Commandments is how they vary in phrasing:

some are just two words, links "don't murder", "don't [commit] adultery", or "don't steal"
some include lengthy Halachic details, like idolatry
some include mention of reward and punishment, like honoring parents or idolatry
some include explanations, like why keep Shabbos

Apparently, the pattern is consistent with the rest of the Torah commandments - some, like sacrifices and Templeic works, are incredibly detailed, while others, like sleeping with one's daughter, are not even mentioned.
On the other hand, since we hold the existence of the Oral tradition from Moses, in theory, for each commandment, the first two words would suffice, as we have on the Luchos in our shuls.
What could account for such a lack of uniformity in the Ten Commandments?
